# Button back in top android menu is missing

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menu, back-button

I use Android Studio 1.5 to create an Android application.

I added a blank activity using context menu but I forgot to define a hierarchical parent for that activity.

So I changed in **AndroidManifest.xml** this

```
  <activity
            android:name=".CategoriesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categories"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
```

to this

```
  <activity
            android:name=".CategoriesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categories"
            android:parentActivityName=".CitiesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="info.emitikon.mycity.CitiesActivity" />
        </activity>
```

**Anyway I cannot see the BACK arrow button at the top menu.**

What do I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines in the `onCreate` method of your `Activity`:

```
ActionBar = getActionBar(); // or getSupportActionBar() if you are using the suport library

actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher); // your custom icon
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Well... As I see other activities that I created using GUI don't have any extra  code and BACK button is visible and works fine.

Comment: It must be something that you are missing, some code that you didn't post. Did my solution work for you ?

Comment: Sorry... This part is red ic_launcher and this part as well setDisplayShowHomeAsUpEnabled

Comment: Of course it would be red... change it to the resource ID of an existing image in your app, any image.

Comment: You are right. `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` was mising